# Apptainer on macOS

Tags: apptainer

I would like to use apptainer for a specific program on my macOS. I have installed apptainer through lima. However, although apptainer is my path, I am still not able to use it.

This is how it looks like now in my path:
`/users/-myname-/.lima/apptainer:/Users/-myname-/.lima/bin:/opt/homebrew` etc.

However, after using a apptainer command, it still gives: command not found:apptainer

I someone able to help me with executing apptainer on macOS?